Determine if matplotlib figure is still displayed (has not been closed)
When using matplotlib in interactive mode, I need to know, whether a figure has been closed or not. I'm tracking the figure handles for other purposes, but the event of closing the figure is decoupled from this (closed by user or by existing code base not aware of the tracking). So the particular figure object keeps existing and I need to find, that its figure (window) has been closed (to know, e.g., that it should not be saved or that the variable can be cleaned).
The situation is in a code like this (tested in python 3.12 with matplotlib 3.9.2):
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.use('qt5agg')
plt.ion()

f1 = plt.figure()
f1.gca().plot(1, 1, 'ro')
print(f1.number)  # 1

f2 = plt.figure()
f2.gca().plot(1, 1, 'bo')
print(f2.number)  # 2


plt.pause(5)

plt.close(f2)

f3 = plt.figure()
f3.gca().plot(1, 1, 'go')
print(f3.number)  # also 2 !!!!

# now we want to save only the figures that have not been closed

# if not closed f1
f1.savefig('f1.png')

# if not closed f2 --- how to find, that f2 is closed and not execute the next line?
f2.savefig('f2.png')

# if not closed f3
f3.savefig('f3.png')

All solutions I have found (e.g. here) propose using plt.fignum_exists(), which cannot be used in a general situation when additional figures are later created, as the fignums of closed figures seems to be recycled.

If you have control over figures, you can use labels instead of numbers:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path


def is_closed(fig):
    label = fig.get_label()
    if not label:
        raise ValueError("Figure must have a label.")
    return label not in plt.get_figlabels()


def clean():
    Path("f1.png").unlink(missing_ok=True)
    Path("f2.png").unlink(missing_ok=True)
    Path("f3.png").unlink(missing_ok=True)


clean()

plt.ion()

f1 = plt.figure(label="f1")
f1.gca().plot(1, 1, "ro")

f2 = plt.figure(label="f2")
f2.gca().plot(1, 1, "bo")

plt.pause(5)
plt.close(f2)

f3 = plt.figure(label="f3")
f3.gca().plot(1, 1, "go")

if not is_closed(f1):
    f1.savefig("f1.png")

if not is_closed(f2):
    f2.savefig("f2.png")

if not is_closed(f3):
    f3.savefig("f3.png")

assert Path("f1.png").exists()
assert not Path("f2.png").exists()
assert Path("f3.png").exists()

clean()

